# Error in Firemonkey standard TakePhotoFromCamera action on Android API 24+

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin, android-fileprovider

I'm working on an Android application in Delphi 10.1 Berlin Update 2, which uses the standard `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction`. If I set the Target SDK to 24 or higher, this action stops working and shows an error message:

> android.os.FileUriExposedException: file.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

I searched through the Internet and found some info on this:

[Delphi Android file open failure with API 26](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50784109/)

[android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/test.txt exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/)

[What is android.os.FileUriExposedException and what you can do about it](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0)

But none of them were about the Camera action, and not directly about Delphi.

I am still new to Delphi, I found a FileProvider API library on [GitHub](https://github.com/DelphiWorlds/KastriFree), but to be honest, I don't know how to use it.

So my question is, how can I make `TTakePhotoFromCameraAction` work correctly with a higher SDK?

Comment: [File a bug report](http://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero, as they would need to re-write `TTakeFromCameraAction` to support API 24+ properly.

Comment: I'm working on a solution for this. Hopefully in the next day or so.

Comment: Just FYI, the issue/requirement is [described by Google here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes#sharing-files). EMBT are aware of this issue. It's part of the API support update plan, so far as I know.

Comment: I've detailed a workaround that is included in this article: http://delphiworlds.com/2018/06/targeting-android-8-and-higher-continued/